# trigger the modal with code behind C#

Tags: c#, json, bootstrap-modal, code-behind, modalpopup

I have a Login form in asp.net, if the user isn't register into BD, I need that Bootstrap Modal is show (trigger), Its possible call json function from code behind, or send response redirect with the instruction to show modal?

Comment: Oh so sorry, I'm new, but I tried to do it for two weeks, I was looking at some pages, ajax, c# code behind forums, but I can't find it (current I do it but without modal, only redirect to register page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden field (`asp:HiddenField` with `runat="server"` and `ID="myHiddenField"` if you're using Web Forms) and in the code behind set the value of that hidden field (e.g.: `myHiddenField.Value = "login-failed"`) if the login fails.

Then, with some JavaScript/jQuery on the page, check the value of that hidden field, and if its value changed, open the modal. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var hdnField = $("[id*=myHiddenField]");
    if (hdnField.val() === "login-failed") {
        $("#myModal").modal();
    }
});
```